# Title Background Wrapping

Tags: css, css-selectors

Ok, I am pretty experienced at CSS but at this point I am at a loss.

I layed out how I want the title to look like in photoshop:

[alt text http://screensnapr.com/u/qz26q5.png](http://screensnapr.com/u/qz26q5.png)

however, the closest I can approach it with css is:

[alt text http://screensnapr.com/u/s7xi7a.png](http://screensnapr.com/u/s7xi7a.png)

I need the black background to extend to the edges of the image and padding on the right side of the title.

I hope you understand my question! thanks.

here is the html:

```
<div class="glossary_image">
    <img src="<?php echo $custom_fields['image'][0]; ?>" />
    <div class="title">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.glossary_image {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.glossary_image .title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.glossary_image .title h2 {
    display: inline;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your current CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `padding` from `.glossary_image .title` and add `padding-right: 10px;` to `.glossary_image .title  h2`.
You might also want to add `padding-top` to the `h2`.

Comment: though this doesnt really achieve the solution, it helped me in the right direction. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the image the background of a div element, by doing this the overlay positioning should be no problem.

Comment: it is for a wordpress theme, and there are multiple images. the problem is getting the correct padding on the text. thanks though!